# Interpolation is not working for SASS version (v3.5.0.beta.2)

Tags: css, sass

> I am using sass version (v3.5.0.beta.2). But interpolation is not
>   working for variable $rect in the code
>   .margin#{$marginKey}#{$marginValue}#{$rect}

A gist-link for support: https://gist.github.com/AnkitPandey007/6f0fa5b283ef38071b7347f9644cd95d

```
/**
  Margin class generation mixin
**/
@mixin marginClassGeneration($marginList){
  $rect:'rect';
  @each $marginKey, $value in $marginList{
    @each $marginValue in $value{
      @debug $marginValue;
      .margin#{$marginKey}#{$marginValue}#{$rect}{  /* $rect is not printing */ 
        margin-#{$marginKey}: $marginValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Including:

```
$marginList: (
        top:(-388px !important, -42px !important),
        right:(),
        bottom:(),
        left:(),
        margin: ()
);
@include marginClassGeneration($marginList);
```

Output:

```
.margintop-388px {   /*.margintop-388pxrect is required*/
  margin-top: -388px !important;
}

.margintop-42px {
  margin-top: -42px !important;
}
```

Please help how to get the required format "**.margintop-388pxrect**"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `top:(-388px !important, -42px !important)` , you can't have important there. Because it's going to try to take that as value. However If you just remove `!important` it will work as expected.

Check out the codepen with working example: https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/VXZVJZ

```
$marginList: (
    top:(-388px, -42px),
    right:(),
    bottom:(),
    left:(),
    margin: ()
 );


@mixin marginClassGeneration($marginList){
  $rect:'rect';
  @each $marginKey, $value in $marginList{
    @each $marginValue in $value{
      @debug $marginValue;
      .margin#{$marginKey}#{$marginValue}#{$rect}{  
        margin-#{$marginKey}: $marginValue;
      }
    }
  }
}

@include marginClassGeneration($marginList);
```

If you really need to have `!important` you can put it on this line:

`margin-#{$marginKey}: $marginValue !important;`

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot of classes and if any programmer wants the new class then we put the value in mixin marginClassGeneration and get new class dynamically.  Actually I want to handle !important and other together with one mixin. i.e. top:(-388px, -42px !important,...nth)

Comment: You can't do that, because !important is part of the value. So it will always try to take that value. Which of course will fail.